# Are the messages thrown by standard library exceptions defined?

Tags: c++, exception, std

`std::vector::at` throws a `std::out_of_range` if the requested value is not in range of the container.

The constructor for `std::out_of_range` requires a string, which can be accessed through `.what()` when catching the exception.

But I have never seen anything written about what must actually be in that message. This can be useful to know for at least two reasons:

- I might want to display this message to a user, for example when running with debug options enabled. Then it is good to know if there are any limits on the length, language, character set, etc.
- I might want to use `std::out_of_range` in my own class if it is similar enough to a standard container, and return a message that is in line with the format used in the standard library.

Is this defined in the standard? If not, is it defined to *not* be defined?

Comment: Exception text should never be shown to the user unless you created the text yourself.  It will almost certainly not be anything other than English ASCII, but more to the point it won't be useful to users in 99% of cases.  You should catch exceptions and show the user something actually useful, such as *"Your name does not fit in our 1980's style database, so we have mutated it for you.  Your name is now ${NAME}.  Welcome."*

Comment: @JohnZwinck It would be nice if you could write that as an answer instead so proper references can be added, and voted on accordingly. You seem to _know_ this for sure, but a lot of people "know" things that may or may not be true.

Answer (score 2):

I searched through n4659 (early c++17 draft).

There is no reference to the string used to initialise these exceptions when thrown by the standard library at all.

I did not see a guarantee that the string would be printable, although I suspect that in all implementations they will be:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf